# Observing number of TCP connections in Gatling simulation

Tags: gatling

The standard Gatling's report shows amount of active users and requests per second, however I need to look at the number of physical TCP connections being created/closed/reused across the simulation. Is that possible?

P.S. I've got the `shareConnections` enabled as I'm not interested in web-browser simulation, but in pure bombardment of my API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Gatling doesn't expose the HTTP client internals.

We'll provide this kind of network metrics in our upcoming commercial product, not in the open source project.